# Can someone who has been Feebleminded have their Int and Cha scores changed via Polymorph?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, ability-scores

I'm running a campaign at the moment and one of the characters got *[feeblemind](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind)*-ed.

If another character used [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) to change them into something with higher Intelligence and Charisma, would this work?

Comment: @V2Blast Spell names in 5e aren't proper nouns, so they shouldn't be capitalized in the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes**

Assuming you are talking about the [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) spell (other spells may vary but most will actually have the same effect).

The spell states:

> The target's game statistics, **including mental ability scores**, are
>   replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast. It retains its
>   alignment and personality.

So if the target is polymorphed into something with higher mental ability scores then yes - they may end up smarter, wiser and/or more charismatic! At least until *polymorph* ends.

Note:

Some argue that this would not work because Feeblemind, being a higher-level spell, would override a standard Polymorph.

However, as Mindwin points out in [his own answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/130088/28591), the rules about overlapping spell durations (which states only the most potent effect applies) would *not* apply here because Feeblemind is an *instantaneous* spell. Its effects may last a long time, but the actual spell itself is instant. Hence even a standard level casting of [*polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) would temporarily override those effects.

Comment: Could you polymorph a person into itself to "cure" feeblemind, then? (If I need to post a separate question, go ahead and tell me)

Comment: Probably a separate question, though I would say that the Polymorph spell is restrictive into what you can change into ("a *beast* whose challenge rating is equal to or less than the target's challenge rating or level"). Higher level spells may be less restrictive

Comment: The ability score isn't the creature's own during the duration of the Feeblemind. It is the affect of a spell. I don't think this would be intended, although JC has made some really silly rulings in the past.

Comment: @berrym. only the species. You cannot transform a person into Obama's pet dog for example, just into a 'dog'. Even if it could transform Galadriel into an elf, it would be a generic elf maiden, not the queen of Lorien.

Comment: Yeah, the beast-only part of Polymorph slipped my mind for a moment. True polymorph would indeed allow them to be transformed into generic-elf-female-423.

Comment: Added a note to counter arguments to the contrary, referring to Mindwin's answer.

Answer (score 4):

#### Yes

Feeblemind is a instantaneous spell with a lasting effect that grants a save to remove.

> On a failed save, the creature's Intelligence and Charisma scores become 1.  [...]
>
> At the end of every 30 days, the creature can repeat its saving throw against this spell. If it succeeds on its saving throw, the spell ends.

Instantaneous spells do their effect then end. Feeblemind won't keep a check on the INT and CHA scores to set them to 1 every turn. It sets those scores once, and then it is done. Save every 30 days to revert back.

Given this characteristic of  instantaneous spells (they don't linger as a spell effect), anything that modifies either INT or CHA scores later will have their effect. Including polymorph. The save every 30 days would still be rolled.

Answer (score 1):

## No.

I would say that the 8th level Feeblemind would override the 4th level Polymorph.

> A spell’s level is a general indicator of how powerful it is.

The rules only describe how the same spell can affect a target multiple times, but the logic seems sound for opposite effects.

> The effects of different Spells add together while the durations of those Spells overlap. The effects of the same spell cast multiple times don’t combine, however. Instead, the most potent effect—such as the highest bonus—from those castings applies while their durations overlap.

Also, Feeblemind describes specifically how to be ended.

> The spell can also be ended by greater restoration, heal, or wish.

Polymorph is not an option.

I would only allow Polymorph to override Feeblemind if upcast with a level 8 or 9 slot.

Comment: Note that the duration of *feeblemind* is  instantaneous so the duration will not overlap with anything. So, the rules you cite seem to have no bearing on the issue.